# What is a possible workaround for object slicing in c++?

Tags: c++

This is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
  virtual const string f() const { return "A"; }
};
class B : public A {
public:
  const string f() const { return "B"; }
};
int main(int ac, char** av) {
  vector<A> v;
  v.push_back(B());
  cout << v.at(0).f() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Expected result is `B`, but it's `A`. As I understand **object slicing** is taking place. How to avoid it? Shall I store pointers in `vector` instead of object instances? Is this the only choice?

Comment: Object slicing, although happening here, is not what causes the wrong result, it is the function invocation by member operator (.) Virtual functions need to be invoked with the member-by-pointer operator (->) 
(except when using references)

Comment: @Ozan: nonsense. Calling a virtual member function from another member function (virtual or not) will also result in a virtual call.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to point out to Vincenzo that using the member operator, not object slicing, was the culprit. It is a common mistake when java/c# people write c++

Comment: @Oznan: NO. Using the member operator is *not* the problem here.  If OP stored pointers instead of values, and called using the dot operator like this: `cout << (*v.at(0)).f() << endl;` it would still call the virtual method and produce `B`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to store pointers. If these refer to dynamically allocated objects, use *smart pointers*.

Answer (score 14):

Ordered from most simple, to most complex (but most nice).

**Solution 1:**

```
vector<B> v;
v.push_back(B());
cout << v.at(0).f() << endl;
```

**Solution 2:**

```
vector<A*> v;
v.push_back(new B());
cout << v.at(0)->f() << endl;
while(!v.empty()) { delete v.back(); v.pop_back(); }
```

**Solution 3:**

```
vector<boost::shared_ptr<A>> v;
v.push_back(boost::make_shared<B>());
cout << v.at(0)->f() << endl;
```

If you don't want slicing to happen, you need to take into account the fact that different objects may have different sizes -- ergo you need a solution that can work with variable sizes -- that makes storing on the heap a must.

Comment: `vector<std::auto_ptr<A>> v;` is really bad idea. Never store `auto_ptr` in a vector, as its copy ctor modifies the passed object.
See this:http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm for the reason.

Comment: I'm sure it's actually _forbidden_ to do that. `std::auto_ptr` doesn't meet the requirements for a container element.

Comment: @sbi, duh, I never use `auto_ptr` and mixed it up with `scoped_array` -_-, corrected

Comment: hey!! i was also searching for the same solution..i like the solution the most:-)

Answer (score 3):

Well, in your code you could use a vector of B. Note that virtual functions will only be dispatched properly if called via a pointer or a reference. However, assuming you really want your vector to contain both A and B objects, you need to make it  vector of A pointers, and create the A and B objects dynamically.