# run time type information (why this code don't work)

Tags: c++, inheritance, rtti

I have a code similar to this (simplified to help present the problem)

```
  class a
  {
   protected:
      int m_x;
  public: 
      a(int x):m_x(x){};
      ~a(){};
      virtual int GetX()=0;
  }

  class b:public a
  {
   public: 
   b(int x):a:(x){};
    ~b(){};
      virtual int GetX(){return m_x+2;};
  }
  class c:public a
  {
   public: 
   c(int x):a:(x){};
    ~c(){};
      virtual int GetX(){return m_x+4;};
  }
```

I also have these functions:

```
vector<a> GetData()
{
     vector<a> data;
     data.push_back(b(1));
     data.push_back(c(1));
 }

 void printData()
 { 
      vector<a> data=GetData();
      for(int I=0;i<data.size();I++)
      {
             cout<< data[I].GetX()<<endl;
      }
 }
```

The above program did not compile by error that a class with virtual function can not be instantiated.

so I changed a to this one:

```
class a
  {
   protected:
      int m_x;
  public: 
      a(int x):m_x(x){};
      ~a(){};
      virtual int GetX()={return m_x};
  }
```

But I am not getting the correct result as I thought since I created objects of type b and c then when I call GetX, their function should be called and not of a. so I am getting this data:

```
1
1
```

instead of

```
 3
 5
```

How can I fix this problem?

Is there any switch in compiler that I should turn on to get this to work?

I am using visual studio 2012.

Comment: This problem is called "object slicing".

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a possible workaround for object slicing in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973301/what-is-a-possible-workaround-for-object-slicing-in-c)

Comment: You, probably, want to use something like `std::vector< a *>` with elements pointing to either `b` or `c` objects...

Comment: The destrutor of you base class should be virtual.

Comment: @LokiAstari: why the destructor should be virtual? It is blank anyway.

Comment: @mans: Because if you call the destructor on a base class pointer it needs to find the actual derived class destructor. To do this the destructor must be virtual (otherwise only the base class destructor gets called). If you fail to declare the base class constructor virtual and call delete on it then it is undefined behavior. Turn on your warnings and the compiler will tell you this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a vector of pointers.  Fortunately, since you are using VS2012, you have modern smart pointers (with some other C++11 goodness):

```
typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<a>> DataVector;

DataVector GetData() {
    DataVector data;
    data.push_back(std::unique_ptr<b>(new b(1)));
    data.push_back(std::unique_ptr<c>(new c(1)));
    return data;
}

void PrintData() { 
    for(const auto & datum : GetData())
        std::cout << datum->GetX() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Identifiers ending in `_t` are reserved for  the implementation please don't use them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/14065

Comment: I prefer using `boost::ptr_vector`. You put in pointers (and it takes ownership) but they are treated as values in all other respects and this makes it much easier to use them with standard algorithms (as you don't need to de-reference before usage).

Comment: It may be worth explaining why (usually you should mention slicing in an answer like this).

Comment: Thanks for the point on `_t`, did not know that one.  I like to stay away from `boost::` in simple problems, since often the people that are reading these sorts of questions are barely getting their feet wet, and installing a library is sometimes daunting (especially for the typical early visual studio user, I've found anyways) and unnecessary since that's beyond the scope of the question.