Polymorphism alternatives when working with CUDA in C++
Edit: From the replies, I realized that what I really need is an alternative to virtual class methods in CUDA C++. I believe the solution proposed are better suited for my use case than the one proposed in How to implement device side CUDA virtual functions?, especially due to having to handle a vector of Virtual classes.
Original question: I am trying to write a path tracer in C++ using CUDA, I am now at a point in which I am trying to pass an array of Shapes to the render function but even though these have been copied to device memory, I get an illegal memory access when trying to access methods of the shapes. I might be something to do with the way I am structuring the classes and their inheritance.
I have a host function render that accepts a scene dscriptor and an image array
__host__ void render(const std::shared_ptr<Scene> &scene, uchar4 *image);

this function calls a kernel renderImage which accepts a number of parameters and in particular my array of Shapes
__global__ void renderImage(const uint16_t width, const uint16_t height,
                            uchar4 *image, const Vec3 origin,
                            const Vec3 pixel00, const Vec3 deltaU,
                            const Vec3 deltaV, const Shape **shapes,
                            const size_t num_shapes);

A shape is defined as
// shape.cuh
#pragma once

#include "cuda_path_tracer/ray.cuh"

class Shape {
public:
  Shape() = default;
  Shape(const Shape &) = default;
  __host__ __device__ Shape(Shape &&) = delete;
  auto operator=(const Shape &) -> Shape & = default;
  __host__ __device__ auto operator=(Shape &&) -> Shape & = delete;
  virtual ~Shape() = default;
  __host__ __device__ virtual auto hit(const Ray &r) const -> bool = 0;
  __host__ __device__ virtual auto getShapeType() const -> ShapeType = 0;
};

A shape derived from the abstract class looks like this:
// sphere.cuh
#pragma once

#include "shape.cuh"

class Sphere : public Shape {
public:
  __host__ __device__ Sphere(const Vec3 &center, float radius);
  __host__ __device__ auto hit(const Ray &r) const -> bool override;
  __host__ __device__ auto hitt() const -> bool override;
  __host__ __device__ auto getShapeType() const -> ShapeType override;

private:
  Vec3 center;
  float radius;
};

and is implemented like this
// sphere.cu
#include "cuda_path_tracer/sphere.cuh"

__host__ Sphere::Sphere(const Vec3 &center, const float radius)
    : Shape(), center(center), radius(radius) {}

__host__ __device__ auto Sphere::hit(const Ray &r) const -> bool {
  Vec3 const oc = r.getOrigin() - center;
  float const a = r.getDirection().dot(r.getDirection());
  float const b = 2.0f * oc.dot(r.getDirection());
  float const c = oc.dot(oc) - radius * radius;
  float const discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
  return discriminant > 0;
}

Shapes are copied in device memory in the host's render function in the following way
const auto num_shapes = scene->getShapes().size();
const Shape **d_shapes;
CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_shapes, num_shapes * sizeof(Shape *)));

Shape **h_shapes = new Shape *[num_shapes];

for (size_t i = 0; i < num_shapes; i++) {
  CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaMalloc((void **)&h_shapes[i], sizeof(Shape)));
  CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(h_shapes[i], scene->getShapes()[i],
                              sizeof(Shape), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
}
CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_shapes, h_shapes, num_shapes * sizeof(Shape *),
                            cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
delete[] h_shapes;

Inside of the renderImage kernel I have two device functions that are being called, one to get a ray corresponding to a pixel and one for the color corresponding to the ray, given the array of shapes, the getColor function looks like this
__device__ auto getColor(const Ray &ray, const Shape *const *shapes,
                         const size_t num_shapes) -> uchar4 {
  // Dummy implementation
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_shapes; i++) {
    if (shapes[i]->hit(ray)) {
      return make_uchar4(1, 0, 0, UCHAR_MAX);
    }
  }
  return make_uchar4(0, 0, 1, UCHAR_MAX);
}

the problem is the shapes[i]->hit(ray) generates an Illegal memory access exception, why is that? And how can I fix it?

You cannot memcpy objects with virtual methods. The only way to use objects with virtual methods on the GPU is if you call the constructor on the GPU. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812913/how-to-implement-device-side-cuda-virtual-functions Even then performance won't be great. My advise: Don't do that. This particular aspect of OOP doesn't work well with GPUs. A cudaMalloc per shape is also very bad for performance.

You can use the CRTP to replace virtual methods on C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp. The CUDA docs explicitly state that virtual method calls are not supported on the GPU.

CUDA also comes with an implementation of std::variant with some CUDA-specific modifications to its implementation. The visit function probably works decently well in your use case but I'm not sure that's state-of-the-art for ray tracers and similar problems

Interesting, the CRTP pattern seems to be an almost 1:1 solution for my use case, I'll try converting the code to CRTP even tough I'm not really familiar with C++ templatating.
Interesting also the solution using std::variant, I'm not too familiar with C++, I'll read a bit into it

@Johan Virtual methods are supported with restrictions. Regarding CRTP: How would you implement that for(int i = …) if(shape[i]->hit(ray)) loop with CRTP and different types of shapes? You can't have an array of different Shape<SubType> objects or pointers. I guess you can combine it with variant though

If you know all the (derived) types you can probably work out something that uses static polymorphism (CRTP is one of those patterns)

Dynamic polymorphism has certain software engineering advantages but even on the CPU it should be avoided in performance-sensible parts of code like hot loops. A GPU kernel is almost always performance-sensible and therefore it makes little sense to use it even if it is possible. Data oriented programming is preferred over OOP for GPUs.

@Homer512 I think the final solution would have to be something that uses both suggestions, am I correct in thinking the array that I should pass around should be of type std::vector<std::variant<Sphere, Cube>>? With Sphere and Cube being defined using the CRTP pattern. Thinking about it though the variant makes the CRTP pattern a bit redundant, I'm really struggling to implement this solution in code though

The main benefit for CRTP in this instance is as an alternative to protected virtual methods. It's a good way for the base class to reach into the subclass.

@Homer512 thanks for the std::variant suggestion! I managed to make it work, will post the solution once I have time for it

Thanks to the suggestion in the comments and in particular the tip of @Homer512 I have come to this solution, please tell me if you think it could be done better.
// shape.cuh
#pragma once

#include <cuda/std/variant>
#include "sphere.cuh"

using Shape = cuda::std::variant<Sphere>;

//sphere.cuh
#pragma once

#include "ray.cuh"
#include "vec3.cuh"

class Sphere {
public:
  __host__ __device__ Sphere(const Vec3 &center, float radius);
  __device__ auto hit(const Ray &r) const -> bool;

private:
  Vec3 center;
  float radius;
};

h_shapes initialized as
const std::vector<Shape> &h_shapes = scene->getShapes();
const size_t num_shapes = h_shapes.size();
Shape *d_shapes;
CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_shapes, num_shapes * sizeof(Shape)));
CUDA_ERROR_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_shapes, h_shapes.data(),
                            num_shapes * sizeof(Sphere),
                            cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

and finally the device function to get the color
__device__ auto getColor(const Ray &ray, const ShapeD *shapes,
                         const size_t num_shapes) -> uchar4 {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_shapes; i++) {
    bool hit = cuda::std::visit(
        [&ray](const auto &shape) { return shape.hit(ray); }, shapes[i]);

    if (hit) {
      return make_uchar4(1, 0, 0, UCHAR_MAX);
    }
  }
  return make_uchar4(0, 0, 1, UCHAR_MAX);
}


The point was to use cuda::std[variant|visit] not std::. Then it should work independent of compiler and that constexpr flag (which can cause hard to find bugs when used with code that throws exceptions).

Ah, thanks! First time working with CUDA, I had assumed it would override std library calls

But then should I define two "Shape" types, one for device and one for host, and then perform the conversion from host to device implicitly with the cudaMalloc?

A couple of comments. Sorry for the spam. 1. Your compilation issue should be a new question because it is a separate issue. 2. That whole overload stuff is too complicated. You can simply use a generic lambda with auto arguments plus duck-typing for the shape classes (meaning, each class has a compatible hit method, even if it is not through inheritance). See here on godbolt.


Using a memcpy to convert between std::variant and cuda::std::variant is not a good idea since they are distinct types with no guarantee that they have compatible inner structure. Normally you would not invoke cudaMemcpy directly on an std::vector anyway because for best performance, you transfer via pinned memory and in copying to the pinned memory, you can convert between both types via proper assignment/construction (placement-new being the proper way).


It also begs the question whether you even need std::variant. If most usage is on the GPU, is there any problem with some usage of the cuda variant in host-side code?

I thought I couldn't use cuda::std::variant in host code, or at least that's what the compiler was telling me but I can't reproduce it so perhaps a clean rebuild was needed. You're right that the compiler error was OT, I deleted it, I didn't think that auto was smart enough to handle this case, that's certainly a lot better thanks!

Everything in cuda::std:: should be available on the host as well. Only things directly in cuda:: are device only.
