# Is there a way to return different types with a single function using inheritance?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to return different types with a single function using inheritance ?

I would want to have something like this, which clearly doesn't work. Any help? thanks.

I don't need virtual functions, which would allow for two different methods to have a different return type. Here, I want a non-member function to return two different types.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
    A(){}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(){bar=20;}
    int bar;
};

A foo()
{
    B b;
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    cout << foo().bar << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `virtual` method can't be used in your code? After your edit, the question can be again closed as duplicate of [Overloading by return type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9568852/514235). As that post suggests, the function cannot be overloaded based on the return type (except some special case of typecasting operators). In your case, you may declare a method in `class A` and `class B`, such as `virtual int getValue () const`. In case of `class B`, it will return `bar` and in case of `class A`, youcan handle the error scenario in various ways, like returning 0/-1/`throw`.

Comment: The thing is, I have a `vector<A*> vect` which contains some `B*`, I want a function which I can use to `vect.push_back(foo())`.

It seems like it is not possible, thank you.

Comment: In your code example, you return `b` as an `A`. Lets say that worked: the program allocates storage for an `A` and copies the relevant parts of `B` into that new `A` with no allowance for `B::bar`. So you can't magically reaquire it - it's not present in the new object so you can't use it. This is called "slicing".

Comment: In your code example, you return `b` as an `A`. Lets say that worked: the program allocates storage for an `A` and copies the relevant parts of `B` into that new `A` with no allowance for `B::bar`. So you can't magically reaquire it - it's not present in the new object so you can't use it. This is called "slicing".

Comment: You either want `boost::variant<A, B>`, or you want virtual functions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973301/what-is-a-possible-workaround-for-object-slicing-in-c

In the exemple, simply using `A *foo()` prevents object slicing, I thought the same could work here.

Comment: @JulienDeCarufel: Do you get *why* that example works? It's because it's using virtual functions; the function called when you say `base->somefunc()` depends on the dynamic type of `base` if `somefunc` is marked virtual. Otherwise it's the static type.

Comment: So `A *foo(){ return new B(); }` would return a pointer to a `B`, which would be distinguished by an overloaded method ?

Comment: **Technically** you don't need virtual functions; you can return an A* which happens to point to a B. But how would the caller know that they got a B, if you don't have virtual functions? This question probably isn't getting answers because of this design flaw.