# c++: when using std::vector, getting error: allocating an object of abstract class type

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual, allocation

I have looked at other similar threads and this problem is different in the sense that I use `std::vector`. I have the following codes making use of inheritance in `C++`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle {
public:
    virtual void brake()=0;
};

class Car : public Vehicle {
public:
    virtual void brake() override;
};

void Car::brake() {
    cout<<"Brake applied"<<endl;
}
```

When I call `brake()` in this way it works:

```
int main() {
    Car c;
    c.brake(); // Brake applied
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I call `brake()` using the following way, I get the error `error: allocating an object of abstract class type 'Vehicle'`

```
int main() {
    vector<Vehicle> vehicleList;
    vehicleList.push_back(c);
    vehicleList.at(0).brake(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Any help on not getting the error?

Comment: You possibly want `vector<unique_ptr<Vehicle>>`

Comment: The "duplicate" explains the problem but doesn't really offer any solution for this use case

Comment: @M.M Thanks. I found some solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973301/what-is-a-possible-workaround-for-object-slicing-in-c